# What is the difference between "hängen" and "aufhängen"?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between *hängen* and *aufhängen*? don't they both mean *to hang*? when should one be used and not the other?

Comment: There are many more, e.g. *abhängen*, *anhängen*, *behängen*, *erhängen*, *verhängen* etc. They all mean *to hang* in their core but in different contexts and at different positions of the hanger.

Answer (score 4):

The Form with *auf-* is transitive, the other is not (usually)

> Der Mantel hängt am Haken

vs.

> Ich habe den Mantel am Haken aufgehängt.

Note also that the first form describes the (possibly long-term) state of hanging whereas the second form denotes the (typically short) act of achieving that state.

---

Then again, there is the transitive *jemanden hängen* meaning to execute a person by hanging. Strictly speaking (or is that already obsolete?) one should  speak of *jemanden henken* instead (therefore also the profession of *Henker* = executioner); also, one often uses *erhängen* for this (in particular when the hanging was not by a sentence, e.g., a suicide "Er hat sich auf dem Dachboden erhängt").

Comment: *henken* is considered "veraltend" by most dictionaries.

Comment: AFAIK hängen may be transitive (eg Ich hänge das Bild an die Wand) or intransitive (eg Das Bild hängt an der Wand). Also, "henken" is indeed obsolete (https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/henken)

Answer (score 2):

By way of continuation of Hagen's answer:

It pretty much depends on context.

For example  in the world of arts, people who prepare an exhibition usually say:

> Wir müssen die Bilder so und so hängen.
>
> Die Hängung der Bilder ist irgendwie komisch.
>
> Habt ihr die Bilder schon gehängt?

They do not want to kill them. It is just common practice in that socio-situative context to speak of *Bilder hängen*, rather than *Bilder aufhängen* (which then is considered a more amateurish way of expressing it).

Whereas speaking of laundry, it is always

> Wäsche aufhängen
>
> Hast du die Wäsche schon aufgehängt?

never *Wäsche hängen*.

Mix these things up and you will harvest amusement or bewildering. - But no worry, you will anyway be understood.

Bottom line: you need to know the various real-life situations and the typical forms of expression associated to them.

The best thing you can do is: keep your ears open for such nuances when speaking with native speakers. Or if you want to use a more scholarly approach: Get yourself a good dictionary (single-language) where examples for typical use of words are given. *Duden Universalwörterbuch* is one of them (that's the big one with about 2000 pages, not the smaller one used for checking spelling). Also available as pdf, if you need to be mobile.

Comment: "Habt ihr die Bilder schon gehängt" und "Hängung der Bilder" sind schon ziemlich seeeeehr grenzwertig.

Comment: @tofro Yes, in everyday usage they are rare. In a professional context they are standard, I would say.

Comment: Professional in the sense of "linguistically professional" or "painting-hanger professional"?  I guess there is a difference.

Comment: @tofro  "Professional" in the sense of exhibition makers (artists and museum curators). - Speaking of "professional in terms of linguist" I think that this would be a cat that bites its own tail: a professional linguist would probably not rule some expression being right or wrong, rather observe he use of language by its users; which may include members of certain sub-groups of the population, e.g. artists and museum curators... A linguist who judges on right and wrong of use of language would pobably rather be called a school teacher.

Comment: @tofro  PS. I am happy to accept information that proves me wrong. I contributed this not as a linguist school teacher  (setting rules) but as a linguist researcher (observing behaviour of users of language). My observations may be wrong, biased, or based on insufficient data.